# How do I adjust the snap size in compiz grid?

Tags: compiz

I'd like to change my snap to by default cover 2/3rds of the right side of the screen when I snap to the right, for example - as opposed to the 1/2 it's doing right now. Is there a way to adjust the default settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a possibility to do this in the plugins options in the CompizConfig Settings Manager (command `ccsm` from the package `compizconfig-settings-manager`):

[image]

Seems to not be possible unless you change the program code and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

Option you requested is not available yet. 
On official Compiz [Wiki](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Grid) the option is first in the list of ideas for further improvements:

*Make the grid size reconfigurable instead of the fixed 33%,50%,66% sizes (ie. Maybe an even better option is to retain the 2x3 grid, but allow the user to specify how big the grid blocks are.)*

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken and my math skills have failed completely, 2/3's of the right half of the screen would actually be 33% of the total. Perhaps you would be so kind as to elaborate on how to select the fixed 33% size.